# Save all attachments to the same directory in mu4e

Tags: mu4e, attachment

Using the mu4e email package, I can save attachments via `A S` (save multi). However, this requires that I specify the location for each attachment separately. How can I configure this so that I only have to specify the location once, and all attachments will then be saved there without my needing to pick the same location for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As of 2021 09 10, Save Multi is no longer available. Mu4e has optional support for `helm`, and that is currently the only way to select multiple attachments to be saved at once. This is fine if you use helm, but if you don't, it doesn't leave you with a very satisfactory approach.

One way to deal with this is to turn on helm mode, but only for this feature. I do that with advice:

```lisp
(defun tws-mu4e-save-all-fix (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Temporarily turn on helm-mode for selecting files."
  (helm-mode)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (helm-mode -1))

(advice-add 'mu4e-view-save-attachments :around #'tws-mu4e-save-all-fix)
```

With this feature, you will use the helm interface to select files, and that allows you to select all files via `M-a`.

Other approaches are found [here](https://philjackson.github.io//emacs/mu4e/email/2021/08/30/save-all-mu4e-attachments/).

## Original Answer (no longer relevant)

It turns out this feature is supported by the customization option `Mu4e Save Multiple Attachments Without Asking`:

> If non-nil, saving multiple attachments asks once for a Hide
> directory and saves all attachments in the chosen directory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [auto-answer](https://github.com/YoungFrog/auto-answer/blob/master/auto-answer.el).

I don't use mu4e, so the following snippet is just a pseudo-code.

```
(defun my/mu4e-save-all-attachments (fpath)
  (interactive "D")
  (let ((auto-answer '(("<prompt-regex>" fpath))
    (<mu4e-save-attachement>)))
```

Each prompt from `mu4e` will be answered by the first prompted `fpath`.

Answer (score 0):

*Doom 3.0.0-pre; Emacs 29.1; MacOS 13 (w/M1 processor)*

In Doom Emacs* using vertico+embark, it turns out this is relatively straight-forward (though not documented in the mu4e documentation as far as I'm aware as of Jan 2024)

1. invoke `mu4e-view-save-attachments` (default EVIL keybinding: `p` when reading the message in 'message view').  You will be presented a list of the message's attachments.
2. Before selecting any, run `M-x embark-act-all`.

   1. this function prompts the user for an action and runs it on all candidates.  So we're going to select any one of the attachments to save, and that action will be applied to all the attachments.
   2. Note that in doom the `Space` leader key isn't available at this point so invoke it via `Meta-x` and typing `embark-act-all`).
   3. Hit `enter` (which selects the first attachment.  really you can select any of them but hitting enter is just quicker)
3. You'll then be prompted with `Run mu4e-view-save-attachments on "X" nils? (y or n)` (where "X" is the number of attachments available).  Hit `y` to confirm.

It sounds complicated but after you do it a few times it starts to become muscle memory. Plus `embark-act-all` will be at the top of your `M-x` actions list, so you'll be reminded of its name there too.

Credit for this goes to https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/p7gvf9/mu4e_how_best_to_save_large_numbers_of/.